# Decorator pattern - how do I NOT call the copy constructor at initialization?

Tags: c++, decorator, copy-constructor

I have an issue trying to use the decorator pattern.  The constructors are printing out addresses for debugging.  Compiled with:

```
g++ -g -o go Decorator.cpp
```

My simplified code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Base created - this: " << this << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class Decorator : public Base
{
public:
    Decorator(const Base & decorated)
    : _decorated(&decorated)
    {
        std::cout << "Decorator created - this: " << this << " created - _decorated is " << _decorated << std::endl;
    }



    ~Decorator()
    {
        std::cout << "Decorator destroyed" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "  This: " << this << ", _decorated: " << _decorated << std::endl;
    }

private:
    const Base * _decorated;
};

class Inside : public Base
{
public:
    Inside()
    {   std::cout << "Inside created - this: " << this << std::endl;   }
};

class Outside : public Decorator
{
public:
    Outside(const Base & decorated)
    : Decorator(decorated)
    {
        std::cout << "Outside created - this: " << this << std::endl;
    }
};

class Group : public Decorator
{
public:
    Group()
    : Decorator(_outside)
    , _outside(_inside)
    {
        std::cout << "Group created - this: " << this << std::endl;
    }

    ~Group()
    {
        std::cout << "Group destroyed" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    Inside  _inside;
    Outside _outside;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hi there" << std::endl;

    Group g1;

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
}
```

My problem is in Group::Group().  I believe initializing the Decorator base part of Group with the uninitialized _outside is fine - the only thing Decorator wants is a pointer to the object.  My problem is that Decorator(_outside) appears to be calling the copy constructor, which I DON'T want.

gdb goodness:

```
Breakpoint 1, _fu0___ZSt4cout () at Decorator.cpp:63
63          Group g1;
(gdb) print g1
$1 = {<Decorator> = {<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x77c34e29},
    _decorated = 0x77c34e42}, _inside = warning: can't find linker symbol for vi
rtual table for `Inside' value
{<Base> = {
      _vptr.Base = 0x401a90}, <No data fields>},
  _outside = {<Decorator> = {<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x22ff58},
      _decorated = 0x401af6}, <No data fields>}}
```

I break prior to g1's constructor and write a couple of _decorated members to known values to help debugging.

```
(gdb) set g1._decorated = 0
(gdb) set g1._outside._decorated = 0xeeeeeeee
(gdb) print g1
$2 = {<Decorator> = {<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x77c34e29}, _decorated = 0x0},
  _inside = warning: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `Inside' val
ue
{<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x401a90}, <No data fields>},
  _outside = {<Decorator> = {<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x22ff58},
      _decorated = 0xeeeeeeee}, <No data fields>}}
(gdb) n
Base created - this: 0x22ff34
Inside created - this: 0x22ff34
Base created - this: 0x22ff38
Decorator created - this: 0x22ff38 created - _decorated is 0x22ff34
Outside created - this: 0x22ff38
Group created - this: 0x22ff2c
65          std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
(gdb) print g1
$3 = {<Decorator> = {<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x4042b8},
    _decorated = 0xeeeeeeee}, _inside = {<Base> = {
      _vptr.Base = 0x4042c8}, <No data fields>},
  _outside = {<Decorator> = {<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x4042d8},
      _decorated = 0x22ff34}, <No data fields>}}
```

After the constructor, g1._decorated has the uninitialized value of _outside._decorated as its _decorated member, which implies the copy constructor has been called.  If I add copy constructor code to class Decorator:

```
Decorator(const Decorator & that)
{   std::cout << "Copy constructor - this: " << this << " - that: " << &that << std::endl;   }
```

it does in fact call it.

If I change the second line of the Group constructor from

```
: Decorator(_outside)
```

to

```
: Decorator(static_cast<const Base &>(_outside))
```

and run gdb

```
Breakpoint 1, _fu0___ZSt4cout () at Decorator.cpp:63
63          Group g1;
(gdb) print g1
$1 = {<Decorator> = {<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x77c34e29},
    _decorated = 0x77c34e42}, _inside = warning: can't find linker symbol for vi
rtual table for `Inside' value
{<Base> = {
      _vptr.Base = 0x401a90}, <No data fields>},
  _outside = {<Decorator> = {<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x22ff58},
      _decorated = 0x401af6}, <No data fields>}}
(gdb) set g1._decorated = 0
(gdb) set g1._outside._decorated = 0xeeeeeeee
(gdb) print g1
$2 = {<Decorator> = {<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x77c34e29}, _decorated = 0x0},
  _inside = warning: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `Inside' val
ue
{<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x401a90}, <No data fields>},
  _outside = {<Decorator> = {<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x22ff58},
      _decorated = 0xeeeeeeee}, <No data fields>}}
(gdb) n
Base created - this: 0x22ff2c
Decorator created - this: 0x22ff2c created - _decorated is 0x22ff38
Base created - this: 0x22ff34
Inside created - this: 0x22ff34
Base created - this: 0x22ff38
Decorator created - this: 0x22ff38 created - _decorated is 0x22ff34
Outside created - this: 0x22ff38
Group created - this: 0x22ff2c
65          std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;
(gdb) print g1
$3 = {<Decorator> = {<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x4042b8},
    _decorated = 0x22ff38}, _inside = {<Base> = {
      _vptr.Base = 0x4042c8}, <No data fields>},
  _outside = {<Decorator> = {<Base> = {_vptr.Base = 0x4042d8},
      _decorated = 0x22ff34}, <No data fields>}}
```

the Decorator copy constructor is NOT called and all appears to be well.  I don't like this solution, as it requires every class downstream to remember to do this.

Is there any way to derive Group from Decorator with a member Decorator and NOT call the copy constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that Decorator(_outside) appears to be calling the copy constructor, which I DON'T want.

What do you expect it to do?

`Decorator` has no constructor taking an `Outside` so the eligible constructors are either:

```
Decorator(const Base&)
```

or the implicitly-defined copy constructor:

```
Decorator(const Decorator&)
```

The first option involves an implicit conversion from `Outside` to `Base` whereas the second involves a conversion from `Outside` to `Decorator`, which is a "better" conversion because the `Outside` to `Base` conversion "goes through" `Decorator` to get to `Base`.

As you discovered, to call the constructor you want you need to do the desired conversion explicitly:

```
Decorator(static_cast<Base&>(_outside))
```

This is necessary, because the type you're passing *really is* a `Decorator` so of course it prefers the copy constructor.

Another solution is to add a constructor that will be used instead of the copy constructor, e.g. a template, suitably constrained:

```
template<typename T>
  Decorator(const T& decorated, typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_base_of<T, Base> >* = 0)
  : _decorated(&decorated)
  { }
```

This will be used for anything which is derived from `Base` but is not a `Base` and is not a `Decorator`

In C++11 you can make it a bit cleaner

```
template<typename T,
         typename Requires = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T, Base>::value>>
  Decorator(const T& decorated)
  : _decorated(&decorated)
  { }
```

Comment: I expected it to "start" at Base and go up, which doesn't make any sense once I read your explanation of "better" conversion :)